Are we really going to accept programming language questions?
So the question:
What tool is used to create the Iosevka fonts?
Now, its true that the heading seems benign. If it was asking for a tool. But if you read the body:

I have come across many .ptl files in the repository, but I can't find any mentions to this language online.

Which the OP reasserts in the comments.
This clearly asks about the language used. OK so i have answered the question because i went out and searched the answer. But generally this should be clearly off topic for GD.SE. (especially since the answer can only be found by googling and or reading sources)
Yes its about fonts, but the language used is not a common tool its an entirely proprietary language of the maker of the font. Which the author has heavily modified to do the task at hand.
But something being about fonts does not make thing graphic design. Just like asking about the machine that makes packages is about graphic design, even though package design to some extent may be graphic design.

The below is my personal view, not rule of law.

Short answer: No.
Long answer: It depends.

I agree with you in this case. This particular question is not asking about a specific programming language that is in no way a graphic design tool. I consider that to be off topic. One wouldn't expect a graphic designer to be especially knowledgeable on esoteric programming languages.
More generally, some programming questions could be on topic. SVG for example is a tool in the designers toolbox, and also (kinda) a programming language. You can use JSX to program things in Illustrator, so that could be on topic. CSS is becoming a fully fledged programming language, and a part of a lot of designer's tool boxes.
I don't see a need to ban every question about programming languages outright. There may even be overlap with Stack Overflow, and that's fine.
I also agree with Wrzl's remarks to some extent. The original question was about how the font was created. Which is a question about making a graphic design product, which is kinda on topic.
But the eventual question was about the templating language that was used to create the font. Which is like asking about the programming language of, say, Photoshop, rather than about Photoshop itself. That's a bit too far down the rabbit hole for designers, I think.
